# Application pool trava e não volta aplicação

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, iis-7

Tenho um sistema em MVC4 no .NET 4.0 que está rodando no IIS 7.

Ele gera o seguinte erro no Event Viewer:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 9/2/2015 11:23:25 AM 
Event time (UTC): 9/2/2015 2:23:25 PM 
Event ID: 625b221bcebd42d3b17ec9efad99079e 
Event sequence: 105 
Event occurrence: 5 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/ifvnetBeta-1-130856770159183370 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: 
    Application Path: 
    Machine name: 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3204 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\IFVNET_PRODBETA 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: 
    Request path:  
    User host address: 191.182.161.49 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\IFVNET_PRODBETA 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 28 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\IFVNET_PRODBETA 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Custom event details:

Já coloquei o `Response.BufferOutput = true`; porém ainda gera o log.

O pior é que depois de um tempo o pool trava e a aplicação deixa de retornar.

Alguém tem ideia do que posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você por um acaso usou `Response.Redirect` em algum método do *Controller*?

Comment: Sim, utilizei. Porém esse erro ele alterna e ocorre até em controllers sem redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Usar `Response.Redirect` é um péssimo negócio em ASP.NET MVC. A chance de você provocar colisão de cabeçalhos de requisição é bem grande.

Evite de usar:

```
Response.Redirect("/ControllerQualquer", true);
```

Troque para:

```
return Redirect("/ControllerQualquer");
```

Comment: Cigano, funcionou em partes. Agora deixa eu te perguntar, top.location do javascript também não é recomendado no MVC?

Comment: `top.location` não tem capacidade de alterar a requisição do lado do servidor, então pode usar tranquilo.

Comment: Cigano, o sistema caiu novamente. E ele está dando problema em uma parte que não usa Redirect.

Comment: Com o mesmo erro ou erros diferentes?

Comment: Mesmo erro, e o controller que acusa o erro é simples pois não é a página Home

Comment: O que exatamente está sendo executado na parte que trava?

Comment: Ele chama uma model que verifica se o usuário está logado, lê um xml e retorna a view passando o conteúdo do XML

Comment: `return View(xml);`?